# A word for the unpleasant taste in the mouth after sleeping uncomfortably

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When I wake up after sleeping on a train or a bus or in the back of a car, I often find an incredibly unpleasant taste in my mouth. It seems as though a few people get this - google has various results for a "metallic taste after waking up" - but I've not heard any word to specifically describe this taste, as in:

> I'm just going fetch a drink - I slept on the way down here and my mouth tastes of *something*

Of course, "my mouth tastes of crap" would get the point across handily, but I'd like a word that literally refers to this specific sensation. Phrases are also welcome. British english is preferred, but I'd happily borrow from other dialects.

Comment: Good question. I think we all know the sensation (though it doesn't have to be _uncomfortable_ sleep to me), but I have no words to describe the taste either.

Comment: The feeling is often described as "cottonmouth" or just "dry mouth".  But as @JanusBahsJacquet said, I don't know a word for the taste.

Comment: The British army metaphor is [*a mouth like a vulture's crotch*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=2iQBAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA51&lpg=PA51&dq=a+mouth+like+a+vulture's+crotch&source=bl&ots=E_m4UYuDAA&sig=Ebu4-qvdMJGjQ8bwz-45qJyZ-xc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiyuLP6hcfRAhXmIcAKHe5MCJYQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=a%20mouth%20like%20a%20vulture's%20crotch&f=false)

Comment: @WS2 One hopes the soldiers possessed good imaginations.

Comment: You could probably call it "morning mouth"....

Comment: [Insults.com](http://www.insults.net/html/expressions/hangover.html) lists some variants:  My mouth feels like the inside of a badger's arse // I woke up with a mouth like a wrestler's jock strap // My mouth tastes like the bottom of a budgie's cage.

Comment: Vultures have crotches???

Comment: I believe the cliché is: Furry mouth. Though there are surely tens of others.

Comment: @Lambie Umm perhaps not. But the very suggestion is hideously evocative. See  [Vultures ?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4-h_Vwpn7c)

Comment: I wrote an answer suggesting "sour" but I deleted it because it was too close to the idiom "have a sour taste in my mouth" which is used to suggest dissaproval of a situation, not the taste in ones mouth!  Still, if you were to say "my mouth tastes sour" , I think that could be a good possibility as we know(at least in the US) sour to not only mean 'tart' but something like milk gone bad.

Comment: It needs to be noted that there are a half-dozen different categories of "morning mouth", from dry and crackly to gummy and raunchy tasting.

Comment: Sounds a bit like yellow tongue, better get a doctor to look at it http://www.healcure.org/tongue/coated-tongue/yellow-tongue/ There is no single word for *metallic taste*

Answer (score 2):

The internet calls it simply [morning mouth](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome-psyapi2&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8&q=%22morning%20mouth%22&oq=%22morning%20mouth%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.8343j0j7).

An example, from [3 Ways To Reduce Morning Mouth](https://essentialoxygen.com/3-ways-to-reduce-dreaded-morning-mouth/):

> We all know the feeling of waking up to an unpleasant taste/smell in our mouth. Morning mouth occurs because, while we sleep, a number of our body’s functions slow down including saliva production.

The term apparently comes from, or was popularized by, an ad campaign from the 1950s. It's doubtful, but not impossible, that it was coined by the "Mad Men" of that era. Here is a screen snap of [an ad that appeared in *Life* magazine in 1953](https://books.google.com/books?id=mEYEAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=%22morning+mouth%22&source=bl&ots=9wR5WOl0Vd&sig=B5NvUQxnR-8d-fFoDekXEVEkcxA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiAvKeGoMfRAhVO1GMKHatrDoAQ6AEISzAJ#v=onepage&q=%22morning%20mouth%22&f=false):

[image: Add appearing in Life Magazine]

Answer (score 1):

The term used by Verner C. Bickley in *Footfalls Echo in the Memory: A life with the Colonial Service & the British Council in Asia* suggests,

***...a mouth like a vulture's crotch*** which I have on occasion heard used, usually by an ex-military type person.

I don't believe vultures have crotches but the thought is enough to make you wince. [This really is fascinating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-4-h_Vwpn7c).

Answer (score 0):

I call it **biofilm** or **plaque**. [This site](http://dentaluxpa.com/what-is-the-film-on-my-teeth-in-the-morning/) has an explanation, here's the part most pertaining to your question:

> it’s almost certain that **the film on your teeth in the morning is indeed plaque . Plaque is a sticky mix of bacteria and the substances that the bacteria secrete**. One of the substances that bacteria produce is an adhesive chemical called mucopolysaccharides which help the bacteria live on the teeth in **the form of a thin film, called “biofilm.”**

Emphasis mine.

It's plaque created by bacteria and their biofilm.

Comment: Please read the question. 'My mouth tastes of/like biofilm'? This explains what contributes towards the taste, but doesn't actually try to communicate what the taste is like.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth "My mouth tastes like plaque" fits perfectly well to me. "My teeth are covered in biofilm" sounds more like something a space alien might say, but this is still useful information

Comment: No, you cannot really "taste plaque". That sound awful to my English-speaking ear [joke].

Comment: @ymbirtt That's what I always say. "My mouth tastes like plaque" or "I've got biofilm on my teeth". Whether or not I can ACTUALLY taste plaque, @ Lambie, doesn't matter because people understand what I'm talking about.